# Show that $\int_0^\infty {1\over{x^4+1}}\,dx=\int_0^\infty {x^2\over{x^4+1}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Could someone give me a hint how to show $$\int_0^\infty {1\over{x^4+1}}\,dx=\int_0^\infty {x^2\over{x^4+1}}\,dx?$$

I know how to do both integrals separately, but this question leads into another way of evaluating them and requires this to be shown first. As such I want to show the equivalence by manipulating the integral as the question intends rather than evaluating both separately.

I have tried working with both sides and I feel like I'm missing a trick. Using integration by parts increases the power of the denominator and no nice cancellation happens(except an unrelated reduction formula). Cannot see a great substitution either.

Comment: All you have to do is evaluated the left hand side, and evaluate the right hand side (you say you know how to do each.  Then show that each is equivalent to the other.

Comment: @amWhy I think the spirit of the question is to see why they're equal without having to know what they are ($\tfrac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{4}$).

Comment: I see not context in the question, @J.G. that suggests what the "spirit of the question", which is all the more reason why we ask users for context, and answerers not to "mind read" and assume what is not there.

Comment: @amWhy I'm sorry, I didn't know you were asking for context. I didn't see a question.

Comment: This is a special case of the [Glasser's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fresnel integral $\int\limits_0^\infty\sin(x^2) dx$ calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273031/fresnel-integral-int-limits-0-infty-sinx2-dx-calculation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that by enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto 1/x$, we find

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^4}\,dx&\overbrace{=}^{x\mapsto 1/x}\int_\infty^0 \frac1{1+1/x^4}\,\left(-\frac1{x^2}\right)\,dx\\\\&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 4):

Basically you want to prove that

$$\int_0 ^\infty \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^4} dx = 0$$

Consider the integral in the $(1,\infty)$ interval. Applying the change of variables $y = 1/x$ we get

$$\int_0 ^1 \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^4}dx - \int_0^1 \frac{1-y^2}{1+y^4} dy = 0$$

which is clearly true.