Integral with a bit of Complex Analysis
I was working on a Calculus Challenge worksheet and came across this question:
Determine whether the improper integral $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\cos (x^2) dx$ converges or diverges, and if it converges, find what value it converges to.
I am completely stuck, I tried some algebraic manipulations of $x^2$ and $\cos(x)$, but nothing worked out. Please help.
Also, if my formatting sucks, feel free to comment and edit the post.

This is called the Fresnel integral, and there are lots of sources online solving this integral. See, for example, the Wikipedia page.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3273031/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4003529/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/187729/42969

The Fresnel integral can be done by contour integral, but it is is bit tricky.

@GEdgar is likely advocating this choice of contour.
