# How to do $\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln(2 + 2\cos(x))^{n}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

For $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln(2 + 2\cos(x))^{n}\,dx $$
I tried doing $$x = 2u$$
$$dx = 2du$$
So it would be
$$2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(2 + 2\cos(2u))^{n} \, du$$
$$2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(2 + 2(2\cos^{2}(u) - 1))^{n} \,du$$
Which simplifies to
$$2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(4\cos^{2}(u))^{n} \,du$$
$$4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(2\cos(u))^{n} \,du$$
Intuitively, I think this integral would be easier to solve, but I can't figure out how to do it. Could someone please tell me how to do it? Or does it need to be with the original integral?

Thank you

Comment: You should add $dx$ and $du$. Also $dx=2du$, i.e., there is an extra factor of $2$ after changing the variables. Use \cos to produce $\cos$.

Comment: OK, I did it now.

Comment: @Gary, I didn't get your point. Could you please elaborate It? I am curious about the solution.

Comment: @Rahul I just pointed out some typos in the original version of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a solution:

Note that $\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2} (2\cos u)^adu = \frac{\pi\ \Gamma(a+1)}{2\ \Gamma^2\left(\frac a2+1\right)}$.
With differentiation in $a$, it can be shown that the integrals

$$I_n=\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2}\ln^n(2\cos u)du $$

are the series coefficients of the exponential function below

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{I_n}{n!}t^n=\frac\pi2  \exp\bigg[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}n (1-2^{1-n})\zeta(n)t^n\bigg]
$$

As a result, $ I_0= \frac\pi2$, $
I_1= 0$
\begin{align}
I_2&=\frac\pi4\zeta(2),\>\>\>\>\>
I_3= -\frac{3\pi}4\zeta(3),\>\>\>\>\>
I_4= \frac{57\pi}{16} \zeta(4) \\
I_5 &= -\frac{15\pi}4\zeta(2)\zeta(3) -\frac{45\pi}4\zeta(5),\>\>\>\>\>
I_6=\cdots\\
\end{align}

Comment: By $J_0$ and $J_1$ you meant $I_0$ and $I_1$.

Comment: @Gary - thanks, corrected

Comment: @Quanto Thank you very much! Could you please give either a proof or a link to a proof for $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (2\cos(u))^{a} = \frac{\pi\Gamma(a + 1)}{2\Gamma^{2}(\frac{a}{2} + 1)}$?

Comment: @MeltedStatementRecognizing see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3271217/583016) for a proof that $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(t)^{2a-1}\sin(t)^{2b-1}dt=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{2\Gamma(a+b)}.$$
The stated result should follow with the right choices of $a,b$.